# Show audio files created with Voice Memos in my own app

Tags: ios, swift

So in my app user can record their voice (already implemented) or choose an audio file from phone. Is it possible to show a list of all available audio files on phone, including those made with built-in Voice Memos app?

So far I tried with MPMediaPickerController but it only wants to show files in Library (if I'm not mistaken those are only music files you get from iTunes). So, here's the code I used:

```
let controller = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .anyAudio)
controller.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
controller.delegate = viewController
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
viewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```